# Dispose old image of Devexpress PictureEdit

Tags: devexpress

I am binding it to XPCollection, how to dispose old image of devexpress PictureEdit control, when a new image is set?

Comment: @Slaks, yes, also updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try handling the `EditValueChanging` event and disposing `e.OldValue as IDisposable`.

Comment: Thanks, weird, no EditValueChanging event fired, only EditValueChanged event fired.

Comment: @Benny: Try the `OldEditValue` property.